# Create custom Windows 10 Quick Actions in Notification Centre?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm currently building some applications for use in Windows 10 and would ideally like to customise the Notification Centre with some custom Quick Action buttons for my apps. Does anyone know if there's a way to create custom Quick Action buttons to launch applications from the Notification Centre?

Thanks,

James

Comment: UWP? What programming language?

Comment: Whatever is necessary for the job, no limitations in that respect

Comment: I've decided not to use the notification centre as I couldn't find any way to do this and instead create a custom swipe in bar.

Comment: I believe, the Quick Action buttons are configurable by OEM's only ([Configure Quick actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/mobile/mcsf/configure-quick-settings)). If you could explain the feature you are trying to implement in more detail, you'd have better chances of receiving helpful feedback.

Comment: The feature is replacing the Quick Actions in the notification centre with my own applications. This is due to not wanting the Users to have access to any of the functionality available from the available Quick Actions (wifi on/off for example) but to use the notification centre as a navigation tool in a locked down kiosk environment. However having done some research I think creating my own version of the Notification Centre from scratch would be easier to implement.